# Ultrafast 2x lossy audio/image compression algorithm?

Tags: compression, image-compression

I'm looking for an audio or image compression algorithm that can compress a torrent of 16-bit samples

- by a fairly predictable amount (2-3x)
- at very high speed (say, 60 cycles per sample at most: >100MB/s)
- with lossiness being acceptable but, of course, undesirable

My data has characteristics of images and audio (2-dimensional, correlated in both dimensions and audiolike in one dimension) so algorithms for audio or images might both be appropriate.

An obvious thing to try would be this one-dimensional algorithm:

- break up the data into segments of 64 samples
- measure the range of values among those samples (as an example, the samples might be between 3101 and 9779 in one segment, a difference of 6678)
- use 2 to 4 additional bytes to encode the range
- linearly downsample each 16-bit sample to 8 bits in that segment.

For example, I could store 3101 in 16 bits, and store a scaling factor `ceil(6678/256) = 27` in 8 bits, then convert each 16-bit sample to 8-bit as `s8 = (s16 - base) / scale` where `base = 3101 + 27>>1, scale = 27`, with the obvious decompression "algorithm" of `s16 = s8 * 27 + 3101`.) Compression ratio: 128/67 = 1.91.

I've played with some ideas to avoid the division operation, but hasn't someone by now invented a superfast algorithm that could preserve fidelity better than this one?

**Note:** [this page](http://fmedia.firmdev.com/audio-formats) says that FLAC compresses at 22 million samples per second (44MB/s) at `-q6` which is pretty darn good (assuming its implementation is still single-threaded), if not quite enough for my application. [Another page](http://tausoft.org/wiki/True_Audio_Codec_Comparison) says FLAC has similar performance (40MB/s on a 3.4GHz i3-3240, -q5) as 3 other codecs, depending on quality level.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [PNG filters](https://www.w3.org/TR/PNG-Filters.html) for examples of how to tease out your correlations. The most obvious filter is "sub", which simply subtracts successive samples. The differences should be more clustered around zero. You can then run that through a fast compressor like [lz4](https://github.com/lz4/lz4). Other filter choices may result in even better clustering around zero, if they can find advantage in the correlations in your other dimension.

For lossy compression, you can decimate the differences before compressing them, dropping a few low bits until you get the compression you want, and still retain the character of the data that you would like to preserve.